# How to create a graphql query with arguments in angular using apollo client library

Tags: angular, apollo-client

I am working on apollo client library for integrating graphql with angular.
I am able to do simple queries like findAll without any arguments

```
const allData = 
        gql`
        query allData {
          allData {
            id
            fromDate
            toDate
            name
            ...
          }
        }
      `
```

I am able to fetch result with this query using watchQuery

```
this.data = this.apollo.watchQuery<Query>({query: allData}).valueChanges
      .pipe(
        map(result => result.data.allData)
      );
```

but I am not able to create a complex query with arguments like

```
{
  allDataWithFilter(
    date: {from: "2010-01-16T10:20:10", to: "2019-01-16T11:16:10"}, 
    name: "ABC" {
    allDataWithFilter {
      id
      fromDate
      toDate
      name
            ...      
    }
    totalPages
    totalElements
  }
}
```

How do I pass date and other arguments in the query?

Answer (score 2):

You should read your schema in order to understand what the server needs and should pass the appropriate data with types. 
I hope it will be something like this in your case.

```
{
  allDataWithFilter(
    date: {$from: DateTime, $to: DateTime}, 
    name: String {
    allDataWithFilter(from: $from, to: $to) {
      id
      fromDate
      toDate
      name
            ...      
    }
    totalPages
    totalElements
  }
}
```

When you are calling this query just pass this data in variables like this

```
this.apollo.query({
  query: YourQuery,
  variables: {
   from: new Date(),
   to: someDate
}
})
```

Comment: The date object doesn't work and gives error on server side. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54258287/how-to-write-graphql-query-wiith-custom-objects

Answer (score 1):

I have defined one of my queries that takes an argument like this:

```
const ListCalculations = gql`
    query ListCalculations($uid: String!){
        listCalculations(uid: $uid){
            details {
                customer
                part
            }
            selectedUnit {
                imgSrc
            }
        }
    }
`;
```

`($uid: String!)` allows me to pass in an argument to the query.
Calling the query:

```
const queryObj:QueryObject = {
    query: ListCalculations,
    variables: { uid: this.authService.cognitoUser.getUsername() },
    fetchPolicy: 'cache-and-network'
};

let obs = client.watchQuery(queryObj);
obs.subscribe(result => console.log(result));
```

Comment: I am able to send query with string but not with custom object date which has from and to. Can you please tell me how your code will work with those fields.

Comment: I suggest you open a seperate question for that. This question was about passing arguments to queries.