# How to write graphql query wiith custom objects

Tags: graphql, express-graphql

The server side of graphql is with nodejs and express. This is the schema for graphql. It has one query which accepts DateT object having from and to dates.

```
var schema = buildSchema(`
    type Query {
        courseWithDate(
            timeFilter: DateT
        ): Course

    },
    type Course {
        ...
        from: String
        to: String
    },
    type DateT{
        from : String
        to : String
    }
`);
```

and this is how I am getting courses

I am able to run the application with this url

```
localhost:4000/graphql
```

This is the query I am using

```
query courseWithDate($from: dateFrom, $to: dateTo) {
    courseWithDate(timeFilter: {
      from: "${dateFrom}"
      to: "${dateTo}"
    })  {
        title
        ...
    }
}
```

with these parameters

```
{ 
   "from": "2019-10-10","to":"2019-10-10"
}
```

Exception message I get is related to the input type I am trying to pass.

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "The type of Query.courseWithDate(timeFilter:) must be Input Type but got: DateT.",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 6,
          "column": 25
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but probably this style looks more like best practice

```
type Course {
  id: Int
  title: String
  author: String
  from: String
  to: String
  description: String
  topic: String
  url: String
}

input DateInput {
  dateFrom: String!
  dateTo: String!
}

type Query {
  courseWithDate(input: DateInput!, name: String!): Course
}
```

And Query on client side should be:

```
  {
    courseWithDate(input: {
      dateFrom: "${dateFrom}"
      dateTo: "${dateTo}"
    }
    name: "${name}") 
    {
      id
      name
    }
  }
```

Comment: I already tried that but on client side I was getting an exception       "message": "The type of Query.courseWithDate(timeFilter:) must be Input Type but got: DateInput.",. My query is     courseWithDate(id: $courseID, from : $from, to : $to) { id,...
}

Comment: still same issue. I edited my question with the code as well. May be this will help to answer the question.

Comment: in your schema, try to change `type DateT` to `input DateT`

Comment: Errors      "message": "Unknown type \"dateFrom\". Did you mean \"DateT\"?",
     "message": "Unknown type \"dateTo\". Did you mean \"DateT\"?",
  "message": "Variable \"$from\" is never used in operation \"courseWithDate\".",
     "message": "Variable \"$to\" is never used in operation \"courseWithDate\".",